# In Python, given a function name, how to get all the modules containing the function?

Tags: python

For instance, there are **os.path.walk**, **os.walk** and assuming another **md.walk**, and assume **os** is imported but **md** is not. I desire a function like

```
whereis('walk')
```

while can return **os.path.walk**, **os.walk** and **md.walk**.

Or if it's difficult to know there is a **md.walk**, how to get the imported **os.path.walk** and **os.walk**?

Comment: What do you mean by 'containing'? All modules that import the object from the source module? That's *way too broad*; you would have to scan your whole harddisk for any and all possible Python source files that could at some point import the module and use the function.

Comment: I do not find the question particularly unclear. The fact that there is no easy answer does not mean the question is invalid. For refactoring (for instance) it can be very useful to know which modules refer to a particular function.

Comment: So now you are looking for a string name. What about modules where `walk` is an entirely different function? Or a method? Or another type object.

Comment: The rephrased question is less clear that the original one. Are you looking for modules which export a certain name or for modules in which a particular function is imported?

Comment: It doesn't matter what 'walk' is. I just need to find them out.

Comment: Add linebreaks and indentation: `for name, module in sys.modules.items(): if hasattr(module, 'walk'): print name`

Comment: @HansThen, the latter if I understood you correctly.

Comment: do you want the line number where the import appears?

Comment: It's nasty to do this for all modules including those that aren't even imported yet. Python doesn't really support iterating over all possible modules, and it's not clear you'd want to - some of them run startup code that could break your interpreter or take a long time to run (think test scripts).

Maybe you just want to do a nice `grep` over all the Python files in a given tree...

Comment: What is the point of knowing where in the entire filesystem, are Python files that are either named `walk.py*` or contain something called `walk`; it would make sense to know "Which walk am I calling?" (which you can find with `walk.__module__`. If you are doing refactoring and want to override `walk`, just modify the Python path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, that's was fun, here's updated solution. Some Python magic, solution for Python 2.7. Any improvements are welcome. It behaves like any other import - so be careful to wrap any of your executable code in `if name == "__main__"`.

```
import inspect
import pkgutil
import sys

def whereis_in_globals(fname):
    return [m for m in sys.modules.itervalues()
            if module_has_function(m, fname)]

def whereis_in_locals(fname):
    modules = (__import__(module_name, globals(), locals(), [fname], -1)
               for _, module_name, _ in pkgutil.walk_packages(path="."))
    return [m for m in modules if module_has_function(m, fname)]

def module_has_function(m, fname):
    return hasattr(m, fname) and inspect.isfunction(getattr(m, fname))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # these should never raise AttributeError
    for m in whereis_in_locals('walk'):
        m.walk
    for m in whereis_in_globals('walk'):
        m.walk
```

Comment: This will only work for modules that have already been imported.

Comment: Caveat: this only works if the relevant modules are imported, but +1 since it's still a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell us more about your use case or larger goals? Getting this answered for non-imported modules is an interesting challenge, and I don't have an answer for the way you've phrased it but depending on your actual use case you may be interested in knowing that may IDEs (Integrated Development Environments) can sort of do what you're asking.

For example if you install [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) (available for free in community edition) you can type a full or partial function name (just a text string) and then have the IDE search the active project to see what you might be looking for. For example you could just type "walk" on a line and then (IIR) Ctrl-click on it to see what possible modules you might have matching functions. You can also search the other direction, seeing where in a project the function is used.

To search on a wide scale you might have to cheat a little and open your Python directory as a "project" but that's easy.

Again, you haven't provided a use case so my apologies if you are specifically looking for, e.g., an in-script way to get that result for later use in a program. If it's something you want an answer to for you, as a developer and as you work, you might look to the tools you're using to provide an answer.