# How to determine which Python standard library module(s) contain a certain method?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given a method name, how to determine which module(s) in the standard library contain this method?

E.g. If I am told about a method called `strip()`, but told nothing about how it works or that it is part of `str`, how would I go and find out which module it belongs to? I obliviously mean using Python itself to find out, not Googling "Python strip" :)

Comment: Something like this: `'strip' in dir(list) would return false` `'strip' in dir(str) would return true`

Comment: That would be horrible if you're using a script to do this. An editor not so bad cause each time you can run the method name. Otherwise pydocs on google search is the way to go.

Comment: In your example, you are choosing two modules that you think it might be in (and one is `str`, so you already have a hint as to the answer). The point is moreover that I want to search the whole standard library.

Comment: @FirebladeDan I would have thought that Python, which is capable of almost anything, would have such a utility, particularly given its introspection capabilities.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084106/in-python-given-a-function-name-how-to-get-all-the-modules-containing-the-func for a script that does it for imported modules and could be extended.

Comment: @Pyderman- Well imagine attempting to traverse through hundreds of documents using the command prompt... no thanks... Plus you have the right attitude python is pretty damn good

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is, `strip` is not defined in any module. It is not a part of the standard library at all, but a method on `str`, which in turn is a built in class. So there isn't really any way of iterating through modules to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [modulefinder](https://python.readthedocs.org/en/v2.7.2/library/modulefinder.html) to determin all the loaded modules then loop though each one and to get a list of methods using [inspect.getmembers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) looping though those to find what you are looking for. I don't thing there is a built-in way to do this.

https://python.readthedocs.org/en/v2.7.2/library/modulefinder.html
https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html